# Private setting in standard calendar from ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, calendar

I switched from 2.3 to 4.0 on my SII and miss an option in the standard calendar app: There used to be a setting for private appointments, which could be seen at the very end during creating a new appointment after selection of extra options. Neither the option, nor the setting seem to exist anymore.

Does anyone know how to set this or has the option been deleted? I need the feature, since I use my synchronized company calendar for both work and other appointments, where privat ones are marked as private in Outlook. I know that there are other calendar apps around, but I like to keep the setup as it was before if possible.

Comment: Are you referring to [this](http://ompldr.org/vZmg3Mg/2012-09-13%2016.08.42.png) setting? The screenshot is from Cyanogenmod 10's default calendar app. I'm fairly sure it's also still there in CM 9 and Sony's ICS.

Comment: @Erik: No, mine looks totally different. I am referring to the default calendar app on an a standard Samsung Galaxy SII.

Comment: *setting* not app

Comment: @Erik Yes it's that setting, but it's gone since my galaxy s ii updated to ics.

Answer (score 1):

I have an SIII on ICS and when I add an event to the calendar I have a "Privacy" option which allows me to choose default, private, or public, however I sync my Calendar with Google Calendar and not with Exchange.

Comment: Hmm why is it different on s2? I had the setting before.